# How to increase textview size programmatically in class in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to increase programmatically a `TextView` size.
My class extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: _tvHeader.setTextSize(23);

Comment: you want to increase the textview box size or the font size ?

Comment: i want to increase font size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code -

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, FONT_SIZE);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code -

```
TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
tv0.setMinimumWidth(px);
```